# How to print all names before scrolling in custom listview in Android

Tags: android

In my application I am fetching all the images and names from a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) server database to the Android mobile. If the emulator screen is [HVGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution#HVGA_.28480.C3.97320.29), only five images and names are getting displayed. In [LogCat](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-logcat-to-a-text-file) also only five names are getting printed. When I scroll the screen, how many names I can see on the screen only that much names are getting printed. Instead of that, all the names has to get printed before scrolling.

```
public class VegdishesListview extends BaseAdapter {
    String qrimage;
    Bitmap bmp, resizedbitmap;
    Bitmap[] bmps;
    Activity activity = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ImageView[] mImages;
    String[] itemimage;
    TextView[] tv;
    String itemname,price,desc;
    String[] itemnames;
    String[] prices;
    String[] descs;
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public VegdishesListview(Context context, JSONArray imageArrayJson) {
        //inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mImages = new ImageView[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.bmps = new Bitmap[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.itemnames = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.prices = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
        this.descs = new String[imageArrayJson.length()];
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageArrayJson.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject image = imageArrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                qrimage = image.getString("itemimage");
                itemname = image.getString("itemname");
                price = image.getString("price");
                desc = image.getString("itemdesc");

                itemnames[i] = itemname;
                prices[i] = price;
                descs[i] = desc;

                byte[] qrimageBytes = Base64.decode(qrimage.getBytes());

                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(qrimageBytes, 0,
                                                    qrimageBytes.length);
                int width = 100;
                int height = 100;
                resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height,
                                                          true);
                bmps[i] = bmp;

                mImages[i] = new ImageView(context);
                mImages[i].setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);

                mImages[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

                // tv[i].setText(itemname);
            }
            System.out.println(map);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vegdisheslistview, null);

        TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.vegdishestext);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.vegdishesimage);
        TextView text1 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.vegdishesprice);
        TextView text2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.vegdishesdesc);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);
        text.setText(itemnames[position]);
        text1.setText(prices[position]);
        text2.setText(descs[position]);
        System.out.println(itemnames[position]);

        return vi;
    }
```

This is my custom listview XML layout. How do I change my code as per my need?

Comment: Post the java code by which you are printing then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listview is created for showing list of large data but with efficiency respective to the mobile device resources.

It reuses view to make it efficient.

The adapter that you provided to the list must have a getView method in it.
That gives the view for each position of listview independently.

And it get called for only those view which are visible to the screen. 
I am sure you are logging down the name in getView.

When you scroll the getView method gets Called again for all the view to be drawn on to the screen.

If you want all the data to printed at once do it before setting the adapter.
but that wouldn't be wise. Infact load only those which are required to be displayed.

Comment: i can change my code..please see my code tell me the solution

Comment: @Javanator how different is your answer from mine?

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction If someone posted a answer which you are about to post then one should always vote up the already posted one. or even comment on that to support that further. This community works this way and trust me i do follow that too. But What you suffered is asynchronous answering at the same time. this happens many a time on stackoverflow. the time i started typing answer there wasn't any answers for me to read.

Comment: To specifically answer your question. No . Your answer is not much different than mine. But if i see from the eye of other person i also find mine answer more descriptive.  May be thats why it is accepted.

Comment: Its not about being accepted or not, your answer is more or less the same as mine... Anyways, no probs..

Comment: :) hey @mirroredAbstraction thats the enjoy part of this community. This race keeps everyone  active for delivering answers. that benefits the answer seeker. so win win for everyone

Answer (score 0):

That is the default ListView operation, in Android ListView it recycles the Views. In other words, it only takes into consideration, the number of items it can place on screen at a time, so in your case you are able to see only those five elements on the screen because of this...

For more, refer to [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html) in the Android documentation.